# Error with reference to `const value_type`

Tags: c++

The following class template is giving me a compilation error:

```
template <typename T> class foo
{
  T attribute1;
  std::vector<foo*> attribute2;  

 public:
  foo(const T& data):attribute1(data){}

  // Some methods

  foo* getAttribute2(int pos)const
  {
    if (pos<0 || pos>=attribute2.size()) 
        throw "In foo::getAttribute2, argument out of range";
    return attribute2[pos];
} 
  void append(foo<T>* element) {attribute2.push_back(element);}

  void foo2vector(std::vector<T>& v)
  {
    v.push_back(attribute1);
    if (attribute2.size()>0) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<attribute2.size();i++) 
            attribute2[i]->foo2vector(v);
    }
  }

void display3()const
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    foo2vector(v);
    std::reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
    for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
        std::cout<<v[i]<<"\t";
}

};
```

The idea of the `foo2vector` method is to put `attribute1` in a vector, as well as all `attribute1`s of all the elements stored in `attribute2` (they are finite).

In the line `v.push_back(attribute1)`, I have the error :

```
Reference to type const value_type(aka foo<int> *const) could not bind to an rvalue of type const foo<int>*
```

when I use the class with `int` in `main`.

```
foo<int>* root=new foo<int>(12);
root->append(new foo<int>(8)); // node 0
root->append(new foo<int>(23)); // node 1
// Sons of node 0
(root->getAttribute2(0))->append(new foo<int>(4));
(root->getAttribute2(0))->append(new foo<int>(9));
// Sons of node 1
(root->getAttribute2(1))->append(new foo<int>(17)); // node 4
root->display3();
```

Comment: `foo(const T& data):attribute(data){}` is wrong it should be `foo(const T& data):attribute1(data){}`

Comment: Oh, that is just an error of typing. In my code, I have `foo(const T& data):attribute1(data){}`. Corrected it !

Comment: Please post your `main` as well, and all other code needed to produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: After the edit, there is no error, we need a minimal example and please be more careful in what you post in the future. :)

Comment: The answers given here were before edit.Op edited again...

Comment: Please be more careful with code you post in the future. It should be something we could directly copy & paste to e.g. [ideone](http://ideone.com/) and observe the behaviour you describe. Missing semicolons, identifier typos, bad indentation etc. should be fixed by you *before* you post, not by SO members spending their free time to help you.

Comment: I didn't know about ideone. I'll use it next time to post a proper code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, since your edit is just useless.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> class foo
{
  T attribute1;
  std::vector<foo*> attribute2;  

 public:
  foo(const T& data):attribute1(data){}

  // Some methods

  foo* getAttribute2(int pos)const
  {
    if (pos<0 || pos>=attribute2.size()) 
        throw "In foo::getAttribute2, argument out of range";
    return attribute2[pos]; // One can also use "return sons.at(pos)" which handles itself range problems
} 

  void foo2vector(std::vector<T>& v)
  {
    v.push_back(attribute1);
    if (attribute2.size()>0) 
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<attribute2.size();i++) 
            attribute2[i]->foo2vector(v);
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
   foo<int> f(5);
   std::vector<int> v;
   f.foo2vector(v);
   std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9edb12ed8ce3e64a)</kbd>**

So take that example in mind and try to work on your logic.

Also notice I used `unsigned int` in the for loop, in order to get rid of the warning (use `-Wall`).

---

Tip: I did not downvote, but that came because of the non-helpful edits and the initial too many typos in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine except few things

```
foo(const T& data):attribute(data){} is wrong it should be
foo(const T& data):attribute1(data){}
                            ^^
```

**syntax error at the end the end of class**

```
template <typename T> class foo
{
  T attribute1;
  std::vector<foo*> attribute2;  
 public:
foo(const T& data):attribute1(data){}
// Some methods
void foo2vector(std::vector<T>& v)
{
  v.push_back(attribute1);
  if (attribute2.size()>0) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<attribute2.size();i++) 
            attribute2[i]->foo2vector(v);
    }
}
};   //it was missing   please correct
```

See the solution link http://ideone.com/gXqRbm

Comment: That I have too in my code. I edited it in the topic :)

Comment: yes i have checked your edit .Please accept solution

Comment: @dada Don't post a wall of unrelated code, but do post all code necessary to reproduce the error. Simply read what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is, and post one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple error in const-correctness. `display3` is `const`, but you're calling `foo2vector()` in it, which is not `const`. The error message generated by [ideone's gcc](http://ideone.com/7i1HLP) is quite helpful. To fix this, simply mark `foo2vector()` as `const`:

```
void foo2vector(std::vector<T>& v) const
{
  v.push_back(attribute1);
  if (attribute2.size()>0) 
  {
      for(unsigned int i=0; i<attribute2.size();i++) 
          attribute2[i]->foo2vector(v);
  }
}
```

[[Live example]](http://ideone.com/eG448v)

Comment: No, (s)he calling `tree2vector()`, not `foo2vector()`.

Comment: @G.Samaras There's no `tree2vector()` function defined in the OP's code, and from the terminology used (`root`, `children` etc.), I hazarded a guess that the OP renamed `tree` -> `foo` for the purpose of posting, and missed one occurrence. It makes sense to me.

Comment: Oh I see, so I am right, but you made the edit in his post. Well that makes sense. However I do not like that we had to spend so much time here and especially you, trying to imagine the code of the OP. OP should learn how to ask a question!